# Auto restarting a program with batch

Tags: batch-file

My current program runs its tasks, then closes itself, the batch file then restarts it after 60 seconds. The problem is that sometimes the program is unable to close itself, and everything is stuck.

I need to modify the script, so it will autorestart after 5 minutes, if the program does not close itself.

```
:launch

START /wait program.exe 

rem delay 60 seconds
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 60 > nul

GOTO :launch
```

Comment: So you are looking for the `taskkill` command?

Comment: How would I integrate that into the current batch script to taskkill it after 5 minutes, if the program does not close by itself?

Comment: Firstly, remove the `/WAIT` switch from the `start` command; after the delay (`ping`), state `taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq program.exe"`, supposing there is only a single instance of `program.exe` running; also type `taskkill /?` into a command prompt window for usage information; the `tasklist` command supports the same filters (`/FI` switch), so you can use this command for harmless testing...

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that :

For example you check for every 5 minutes if the `calc.exe` process is running or not.

```
@echo off
Mode con cols=55 lines=3
:CheckRunningProcess
Cls
echo(
Set "MyProcess=calc.exe"
Title Check for Running Process "%MyProcess%"
tasklist /NH /FI "imagename eq %MyProcess%" 2>nul |find /i "%MyProcess%" >nul
If not errorlevel 1 ( Color 0A & Echo                  "%MyProcess%" is running
) else (Color 0C & echo   "%MyProcess%" is not running, so we start it right now & start "" "%MyProcess%")
TimeOut /T 300 /NoBreak >nul
Goto :CheckRunningProcess
```